# What's the significance of these characters towards the end of Enchanted?

Tags: plot-explanation, enchanted

During the final ballroom scene in Enchanted, after some commotion, there's a cut away to two old ladies that are only in the movie to provide this exchange:

> Ballroom Lady #1: What did you think?
>   Ballroom Lady #2: Wonderful. Oh, much better than last year's show.

This scene stood out to me like it was supposed to be a cameo of some sorts, but I couldn't place it. The way it's structured makes it an odd fit to be left in the movie if it weren't supposed to be some sort of reference to something else.

Now, I've found that Ballroom Lady #1 was the late [Helen Stenborg](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0826523/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t42) and Balroom Lady #2 is [Anita Keal](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0443773/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t43). Both of these actresses played roles in the TV Series "One Life to Live", but a [full listing of the cast](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062595/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) shows both of them as having been in an unknown number of episodes, so I have no idea if they ever appeared on-screen together.

So, was there any significance to the appearance of those two ladies, or is my mind just trying to find significance where there is none?

Comment: I think it's just a throwaway joke - the idea that actual magic is occurring and the two old ladies assume it's some kind of play.